# Is this correct: "leaning against my back"

Tags: word-choice, sentence

I'm writing in present tense, first person. I want to say that someone is sitting back to back with the main character (narrator). I utilized the following phrase:

> The voice comes from someone leaning against my back.

With that sentence, would you be able to tell that they are sitting back to back? If not, then what would be the best way to say this?

Thanks.

Comment: The posture of the leaning person could be anything. “leaning *back* against my back” would establish the posture. Note that asking for rewrite suggestions is not on topic here. This is a good question to redirect to Writers.SE.

Comment: @MetaEd: I appreciate your comment. I apologize if this isn't in the correct site, and wouldn't mind if it got moved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have given the right answer - ***the voice came from someone sitting back-to-back with me***. I don't believe there is a better way of expressing what you are trying to say.